# Mysql set row based replication for only one table and generate separate bin log from master

Tags: java, mysql, maven

We have build a table about notifications where a program inserts data and then another program get that data and show it to user. That last program is querying each 5 seconds the table to find if there are new data to notify, which i think is not the best way because is hitting every 5 seconds.

I have found that reading replication bin log with java (in this case) can help. But replication needs to be set in the type "row based replication" to be read with mysql-binlog-connector-java, right now our replication is set to "statement based replication".

Is there a way to set this notification table to "row based replication" and generate its own bin log apart from the master bin log? So i can just build a java program to read this notification table bin log.

Comment: Are you sure that "reading a binlog file every 5 seconds" is significantly more performant (and compatible) than "running a query every 5 second against a system whose whole purpose it is to answer questions about data in tables"?

Comment: @Solarflare In terms of performant and compatibility i have no problems, what i am trying to do is for future uses, like increase of notifications and actually all databases are very concurrent so it will also increase in the future, so reading a log file vs hitting every 5 seconds the database, i think the first one is the best try. Is there a way to set the configuration that i posted?